# PackageInstaller.uninstall() method not working in Android-TV (setup box)

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-tv

For a setup box powered by Android(Q) we want the ability for an app which resides in `/priv-app/` section to uninstall packages silently without user interaction.

I have root access to the device.
The app has `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` and `android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES` permissions declared in the manifest.
When the same code is run on Android phones/ emulators with root access it is able to uninstall the app from the device (when the app is made as device owner).

But in case of Android-TV, there is no provision/section for enabling device admin apps, and if I try to enable it using command `adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.tvdevice.deviceadminapp/.DevAdminReceiver`
line it throws error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{com.tvdevice.deviceadminapp/com.tvdevice.deviceadminapp.DevAdminReceiver} as device owner.
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:177)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:106)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:54)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:340)
```

So as a workaround I directly edited the xml files `device_owner_2.xml` and `device_policies.xml` at `/data/system/` to include my app as device owner, but still it is not able to uninstall the app installed from some other package (ex: `com.android.vending`, installer of package for apps installed from play).

Note: The app is able to uninstall the packages which are installed by it (to which the current app is **installer of package**), but it fails for apps installed from other sources.

Is there any way to make if work?, please help.

Comment: You want it to happen silently? without the user's approval?

Comment: @ItayFeldman Yes.. it should be a silent uninstall.